# Haskell No instance for Integral Double

Tags: haskell, double, rounding, integral

I am trying to round a variable using Haskell.

```
r :: Double -> Double
r x = round (x)
```

Trying to compile this, Im getting the following error

> No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of 'round'

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is logical, since a type that is an instance of [**`Integral`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral), well..., is usually "integral". It thus means it is something that behave like an `Integer`. Examples of `Integral`, are `Integer`, `Int`, `Word8`, etc. A `Float`, `Double`, etc. is not integral, like the error says.

You can use [**`fromIntegral :; (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert something that is of an `Integral` type, to a `Num`erical type:

```
r :: Double -> Double
r = fromIntegral . round
```

For example:

```
Prelude> r 14.25
14.0
```

Comment: No this does not work. Double is a frac so I do not have to declare it to one using fromIntegral, do I?
However, it does not work. I am getting same error like before.

Comment: @longroad: then why does the prelude demonstrates with sample output. A `Double` is an instance of many typeclasses: `Enum`, `Num`, `Eq`, `Floating`, etc. hence the `fromIntegral` will specialize to `Double`. The fact that you get the same error, suggests that there is another problem located somewhere else triggering the same (or a very similar) error message.

Comment: this is the whole code in my file: ```r :: Double -> Double
r x = round (fromIntegral(x))``` and I am getting this output in GHCi
>GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             (
\test.hs, interpreted )
test.hs:12:7: error:
    * No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of `round'
    * In the expression: round (fromIntegral (x))
      In an equation for `r': r x = round (fromIntegral (x))
   |
12 | r x = round (fromIntegral(x))
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @longroad: but you swapped the two, it is `fromIntegral (round x)`, note that we call `fromIntegral` on the *result*.